# Magento 2 : Limit to recently viewed products

Tags: magento2

I want to show  only two **recently viewed products** in **products** page.How to add it in layout file in **block**.I am adding like

```
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false">
           <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">recently_viewed</argument>
           </arguments>
           <argument method="setLimit">
               <argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">2</argument>
           </argument>

       </block>
```

buts its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, I assume, you're adding the widget in a Static Block then adding this block in your layout so when you add the `setLimit` method you are technically adding the limit to this block instead of the widget which won't work as you expect.

Instead you should use the Recently Viewed Products widget class directly in your layout like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
    <action method="setPageSize">
        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

This way you will only change the product count for this specific widget. Notice that it's not `setLimit` but `setPageSize` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you are only looking for an XML solution? If not then this change can be made through the admin `Stores > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Recently Viewed/Compared Products > Default Recently Viewed Products Count`

[image]

Comment: I want to show it in product listing and product details page,If i given there it will affect to both.But iwant count in product details page only

Comment: I see, my answer does not help then. I'll leave it here in case it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 : Via Widget we can add **"Limit to recently viewed products"** without adding new static block and adding some logic in this and calling in layout...

Below I added steps to add a new widget for **Recently Viewed Products**

**Note : PDP = Product Detail Page (Product Page)**

So as per asked question we have to set **Recently Viewed Limit to 2** in PDP so

In Admin Panel we have `Content -> Widgets`

**Add Widget**
For Recently view choose widget type **Recently Viewed Products**

1. **Type** = Recently Viewed Products
2. **Design Theme** =  Assign you theme

   **Continue...**
3. **Widget Title** = PDP Recently Viewed Product (title add as per you need or understanding for future reference)
4. **Assign to Store Views** = Select as you need
5. **Sort Order** = (Add as per you need) else leave empty, it will set to 0

**Layout Updates** - Add Layout Update

1. **Display on** = **All Product Types** or select which Product Type You want to display this section (example: simple,config ...)
2. **Products** = **All | Specific Products** -  As per you need you can choose all product or some of products...
3. **Container** = Main Content Area or as per your PDP structure you can choose.
4. **Template** =  As per your PDP structure you can choose or you can override template into your theme if need changes on structure.

Now change the tab to **Widget Options**

**Number of Products to display** = 2 or as you need update this and save

After save **Clear Cache** and see or open some PDP's, You will get Recently Viewed in PDP.

if any concern on this please let me know i will help you out.